# Must Tomcat 7 app be inside appBase?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I'm running Tomcat 7 (via mod_proxy_ajp connector to apache 2.2 httpd) on localhost. My `webapps` folder is set in the tomcat `conf/server.xml` to `/Users/myname/Sites/webapps`.

Is it possible somehow to configure things so that I can have other Tomcat apps in folders *not* inside the `webapps` folder? If so, how?

For example, is it allowed to have additional `Host` entries in `server.xml` -- with separate names, of course, e.g.:

```
 <Host name="myapp.local" appBase="/Users/myname/Sites/myapp"
 ....
 />
```

And then, if that's allowed, do I just copy the usual stuff from the default `Host` entry to such additional entries?

Answer (score 2):

Does docBase attribute of the Context element solve your problem?

```
<Context docBase="/path/to/your/another/webapp" ...
```

You can get more details about docBase attribute here:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes

Suppose your webapp is located in /path/to/myapp. You can deploy your webapp by creating a following xml file.

$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/myapp.xml:

```
<Context docBase="/path/to/myapp">
</Context>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have no idea whether `docBase` in a `Context` element will do what I want: the docs you link to are utterly opaque to me (but then I only have a Ph.D. in math and 58 years experience programming in everything from machine code, assembler, and Fortran upward).

Comment: One thing that's unclear is which files and subdirectories, if any, from the distributed Tomcat `webapps` directory need to go into such other `myapp` tree.

Comment: The cited docs say one should not put a `Context` element inside `conf/server.xml`. But I don't understand what the docs say about where else it may go. In particular, if my app is in, say, `/path/to/myapp`, then: (1) how could I put the `Context` element in the `/META-INF/context.xml` for that application and have Tomcat find it? And (2) if instead I want to put the `Context` element in ` $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/`, do I literally just put the `<Context ... />` element there or does that need to be surrounded by other configuration text?

Comment: Yes, you can just put the Context element into the file. I edited my answer.

Comment: Not working. I have a valid Tomcat app `/Users/name/Sites/webmathematica`. In `/usr/local /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/conf/Catalina/localhost` I put file `webmathematica.local.xml` with content: `<Context docBase="/Users/name/Sites/webmathematica">
</Context>`. After starting Tomcat 7 and Apache httpd 2.2 under OS X, then in browser URL `webmathematica.local` never loads. (If I edit `/private/etc/hosts` to add `127.0.0.1 webmathematica.local`, same browser URL gives apache default "It works" page, not the app.) Note: I route tomcat through httpd via `mod_proxy_ajp`.

Comment: To continue: Could problem involve `https-vhosts.conf`, which includes following standard entry form for `webapps` but no entry for my app? `<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin who@where
    DocumentRoot "/Users/name/Sites/webapps"
    ServerName tomcat.local
    <Directory "/Users/name/Sites/webapps">...</Directory>
   <Proxy *>...</Proxy>
    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/...
   </VirtualHost>`

Comment: In your case, navigate to http://[youripaddress]/webmathematica.local/ to run the app. Your httpd-vhosts.conf seems fine, but DocumentRoot and Directory are not necessarily since ProxyPass is configured to forward all requests to the Tomcat.

Comment: My original question was about putting additional Tomcat-calling apps *outside* the standard `webapps` folder (and of course still have access to that `webapps`, too). If in `httpd-vhosts.conf` I change `DocumentRoot` to point to the additional app, then how do I access the original `webapps` or yet additional apps? Thus my confusion here!

Comment: You do not have to use Apache httpd if you just want to run your webapps on Tomcat. If you navigate to http://[youripaddress]:8080/webmathematica.local/ (access Tomcat directly), you can run your webapp. (Tomcat listens on port 8009 for AJP and 8080 for HTTP by default.) In your case, Apache just forwards the requests to the Tomcat AJP port(8009).

Comment: Either `http://localhost:8080/webmathematica.local` or `http://localhost:8080/webmathematica` gives a "resource is not available" error. Folder with the webMathematica application is `/Users/myname/Sites/webmathematica`-- *not* inside my `webapps` folder. I'm lost now as to what config file entries I should put where for this application. In `https-vhosts.conf` I do have the entry `<VirtualHost *:80>...<Directory "/Users/myanme/Sites/webapps"> ... ProxyPass / amp://localhost:8009/... </VirtualHost>` and in `/etc/hosts` the item `127.0.0.1  tomcat.local`. What else?

Comment: Continuing... `http://localhost:8080/webmathematica.local` gives a "resource is not available" error. Folder with the webMathematica application is `/Users/myname/Sites/webmathematica`-- *not* inside my `webapps` folder. `https-vhosts.conf` has entry `<VirtualHost *:80>...<Directory "/Users/myanme/Sites/webapps">...ProxyPass / amp://localhost:8009/... </VirtualHost>` and in `/etc/hosts` the item `127.0.0.1  tomcat.local`. In the tomcat `conf/Catalina/localhost/webmathematica.local.xml` have `<Context docBase="/MacHD/Users/murray/Sites/webmathematica"></Context>` What else or what's wrong?

Comment: Your configuration seems fine. You may have entered an incorrect URL. If you have /MacHD/Users/murray/Sites/webmathematica/index.html, navigate to http://[youripaddress]:8080/webmathematica.local/index.html. You should see the content of the index.html file. If you have /Users/myname/Sites/webapps/yourapp1/index.html, navigate to http://[youripaddress]:8080/yourapp1/index.html. And, you can access these URLs through the Apache by changing port number. (i.e. http://[youripaddress]/webmathematica.local/index.html).

Comment: But the configuration is evidently *not* working! There *is* an `index.html` in `/Users/myname/Sites/webmathematica`, but neither `http://localhost:8080/webmathematica.local/index.html` nor `http://127.0.0.1:8080/webmathematica.local/index.html` works: both give "resource is not available". (Sorry for any confusion about`docBase`: although my home folder is on a 2nd internal drive (MacHD), to simplify things I'm just describing my home folder as `/Users/myname` and the target of `docBase` as `/Users/myname/Sites`.)

Comment: Where are you suggesting I change a port number??

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why your app does not work. About the port number, I meant to specify port 80 (used by Apache) instead of 8080 (used by Tomcat). `http://localhost/` is the same as `http://localhost:80/`. If you omit the port number, default http port (80) is used by the browser.

Comment: Normally,we configure docBase when we want the application to be resided on
a separate directory and not inside tomcat. So, when you use docBase I
don't think you need to configure host/appbase as well.
Appbase folders go under tomcat directory parallel to default appbase
webapps. Each appbase is mapped to a particular host so we configure more
than one appbases when we want to have applications running under different
hosts deployed in the same tomcat.